# Detect insertion of mobile phone or camera

Tags: c++, winapi

I subscribed to notifications with `::RegisterDeviceNotification()`([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431(v=vs.85).aspx)). After processing some details(message `WM_DEVICECHANGE`([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480(v=vs.85).aspx)), etc), I have `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE`([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363244(v=vs.85).aspx)) structure.

How can i know that inserted device is mobile phone or camera, for example ?

I googled *Windows Portable Devices*([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388998(v=vs.85).aspx)). It's possible to use `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE::dbcc_name` as argument for `IPortableDevice::Open`([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319361(v=vs.85).aspx)). With this it's possible get the list of the "supported" content of a device([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319312(v=vs.85).aspx)), for example:

- `WPD_CONTENT_TYPE_IMAGE`
- `WPD_CONTENT_TYPE_AUDIO`
- `WPD_CONTENT_TYPE_PLAYLIST`
- `WPD_CONTENT_TYPE_VIDEO`
- `WPD_CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT`
- `WPD_CONTENT_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED`
- `WPD_CONTENT_TYPE_FOLDER`

But I don't know if, for example, camera supports only `WPD_CONTENT_TYPE_VIDEO`, `WPD_CONTENT_TYPE_IMAGE` and `WPD_CONTENT_TYPE_FOLDER`?

Another framework is *Windows Image Acquisition*([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630368(v=vs.85).aspx)), but this thing does not see mobile phone(only scanner, maybe somthing else, I don't know).

Comment: Are you asking what the hardware vendor decided to support?  That is the reason why you get the list of supported content.  Cach vendor can choose what they are going to support there is no magic combo.

Comment: No, i'm asking - is there way to detect mobile phone and camera insertion. Because right know - i don't know how to see difference beetween them. Everithing i know is that the user insert device and it's a media device..

Answer (score 0):

If for example you have a wireless mouse.  When you turn the power on on the mouse it will Attempt to connect itself to the dongle, or bluetooth, etc.  If those devices are not currently mounted then they first must be added.  The trigger steps backwards up the device chain until the power on/drop event gets handled by a valid USB driver.

Then each stage must add a driver to the USB stack to handle that device.  And the stack is built up back towards the final end point.  You will receive a notification for each usb driver that gets added to the stack. But you will receive the notification asynchronously with the driver initialization.  So there is no guarantee that the device is available for use at the time you receive the notification.

For this reason it is impossible to identify at the time of notification exactly which device has been added.  But you do get information about the type.

The proper way to find out what specifically the device is is to enumerate the USB devices on the machine.  But be careful.  If you enumerate to quickly you will miss the device that has just been added.

A solid approach is to wait until several milliseconds or even several seconds after you have received the notification to enumerate the USB devices on the machine.  If for example the phone requires that 3 drivers be added to the stack then you would need to wait until you have received all 3 notifications, and wait until those 3 drivers have been initialized before the phone will show up in the enumeration.

The enumeration consists of looking up guids that are present in the registry.  The entries do not get added until driver initialization completes, and then the driver can ask the hardware for its Identifying guid.  Then the guid gets inserted into the registry.  Unfortunately the location in the registry is different for different flavors of windows.

For reference on windows7 take a look at HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB...
You will see a list of every device that has ever been plugged into that machine.  Each VID_xxxx and PID_xxxx pair is a different device.

The best method for enumerating the USB devices that are "Active" and plugged into the machine is via Windows Management Instrumentation.  Trigger this at the appropriate time after the driver has had time to identify the device.  Then in the enumeration call back check the VID, PID, manufacturer, device name, etc to see if it is the one you want.

Sorry I cant find the Windows SDK sample, but here is a good starting point for you, that shows how to enumerate the USB devices to see if one is XInputDevice or not.  You'll want to replace the vid and pid, and checks for the device your looking for : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417014(v=vs.85).aspx

And yes this could be much simpler, but hey if it were simple everyone would be doing it.

Best of luck!

Comment: One other key point.  If you dont let the main thread return via GetMessage() / PeekMessage() then the driver stack may not become available in a timely fashion.  You should set some internal countdown timer to trigger the enumeration and return right away.